# Android GestureOverlayView limiting paintable area

Tags: android

In GestureOverlayView is there any way to limit paintable area. ie in the whole View i want some margin that is not paintable, with the view(GestureOverlayView) covering all the available area

Answer (score 0):

you can try to apply padding in your view. probably in your layout xml, or via code `View.setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`